# Java use Scanner to count words and lines from user input

Tags: java, while-loop, count, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use the Scanner class to calculate the number of words and lines from a user input, and this is my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class newCounter{
  public static void main(String [ ] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    printWords(input);
    printLines(input);

  }

  public static void printWords(Scanner x){
    int words = 0;
    while(x.hasNext()){
      words++;
      x.next();
    }
    System.out.println("words: " + words);
  }



  public static void printLines(Scanner x){
    int lines = 0;
    while(x.hasNextLine()){
      lines++;
      x.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("lines: " + lines);

  }
}
```

I've found that both methods work 100% fine individually, but only the first one called works when together (The printWords method in this situation). Is there any way of combining these methods so that it might work as one loop?

Comment: You'll probably find it's easier to read all the input first, then do the counting afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate the words,lines with the following code

```
 public static void printWordsOfLines(Scanner x){
 Scanner line=x;
 Scanner word=x;
int lines = 0;
System.out.println("Enter q to quite input");
int words=0;

while(line.hasNextLine()){
   String xx=line.next();

   String w[]=xx.split("  ");
   String l[]=xx.split("\n");

   words+=w.length;
   lines+=l.length;

   if(xx.equals("q"))
       break;
  else   
      x.nextLine();
    }
  System.out.println("lines: " + lines);
  System.out.println("words: " + words);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although i'm still not sure I understand. These scanners line & word still refer to the same single input scanner, so again only the line loop works and the word loop has nothing left to loop through?

Answer (score 0):

Every method will read a line from you console. So you have to change to read the line once in a string and then work with it.

```
  public static void main(String [ ] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String line =input.next();

        printWords(new Scanner(line));
        printLines(new Scanner(line));
    }
  }

  public static void printWords(Scanner x){
    int words = 0;
    while(x.hasNext()){
      words++;
      x.next();
    }
    System.out.println("words: " + words);
  }



  public static void printLines(Scanner x){
    int lines = 0;
    while(x.hasNextLine()){
      lines++;
      x.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("lines: " + lines);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you in finding the word count, line count & word count excluding white spaces.

```
String i=null;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int line=0;
i= input.nextLine();
if(i!=null)
{
    line++;
}
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(i);   

int wordcount=sb.length();

System.out.println("Content"+i);
System.out.println("wordsCount:"+wordcount);
System.out.println("LineCount"+line);
System.out.println("Excluding white spaces"+i.replaceAll(" ", "").length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You got good answers here.
Just wanted to sharpen things a little.
In your example, by completing the words counting, the scanner pointer was located at the end of the last word entered - so when you initiated the lines counting, you had nothing to count.

By grasping it, now you better count each lines first. Then count the words via the split method as @Balayesu Chilakalapudi suggested or creating another scanner, running on each lines - as @Jens advised.